# BibTeX & TexMakerX 2.2 SVN

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

Why i get the error below with this settings?

> ### I use:
>
> TexMakerX 2.2 SVN
>
> TeXLive 2012
>
> Windows

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{bibliography}


\begin{document}

\cite{bringhurst:elementi}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

---

bibliography.bib

```
@book{bringhurst:elementi,
author = {Bringhurst, Robert},
title = {Gli Elementi dello Stile Tipografico},
publisher = {Sylvestre Bonnard},
year = {2001},
location = {Milano}
}
```

---

Bibtex command (into the preferences of the editor):

```
bibtex  %
```

---

output

```
Process started

Process exited with error(s)
```

---

.blg file

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2012/W32TeX)
Capacity: max_strings=35307, hash_size=35307, hash_prime=30011
The top-level auxiliary file: dummy.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file dummy.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file dummy.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file dummy.aux
You've used 0 entries,
            0 wiz_defined-function locations,
            83 strings with 484 characters,
and the built_in function-call counts, 0 in all, are:
= -- 0
> -- 0
< -- 0
+ -- 0
- -- 0
* -- 0
:= -- 0
add.period$ -- 0
call.type$ -- 0
change.case$ -- 0
chr.to.int$ -- 0
cite$ -- 0
duplicate$ -- 0
empty$ -- 0
format.name$ -- 0
if$ -- 0
int.to.chr$ -- 0
int.to.str$ -- 0
missing$ -- 0
newline$ -- 0
num.names$ -- 0
pop$ -- 0
preamble$ -- 0
purify$ -- 0
quote$ -- 0
skip$ -- 0
stack$ -- 0
substring$ -- 0
swap$ -- 0
text.length$ -- 0
text.prefix$ -- 0
top$ -- 0
type$ -- 0
warning$ -- 0
while$ -- 0
width$ -- 0
write$ -- 0
(There were 3 error messages)
```

Comment: Look inside the .blg file that will show the error.

Comment: Add `backend=bibtex` as package option for package `biblatex`.

Comment: BTW: Well documented question, easy to troubleshoot. Wish we had more of these on SX. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\bibliography{bibliography}


\begin{document}

\cite{bringhurst:elementi}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```